# Proof of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a SVD for matrix $A= USV^T$, so the pseudo-inverse of A is $A^+ = VS^+U^T$.
And now A belongs to $m\times n$ real space , $b\in\mathbb R^m$, and $y\in\mathbb R^n$. And I was asked to directly check that $(I - A^+A)y$ and $A^+b$ are orthogonal vectors.

So I have 2 questions here.
First, is the problem asking for proving the two vectors are orthogonal, or to prove that each of the two is orthogonal?

The second question is if it is asking to prove that each of them is orthogonal, then for the first expression, I have now derived the expression $(V_2V_2^T)y$, and $V_2V_2^T$ is the projection of Null Space of $A$, but then I do not know how to proceed more. So could you please show me how to prove orthogonality of this vector. Also, for the second expression,$A^Tb$ is $VS^+U^Tb$, and then how should I deal with this?

Please provide me with some ideas about how to proceed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about vectors "orthogonal" is a relation with respect to something; being "orthogonal" for a single vector makes no sense.

In your case, you want to calculate
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\langle (I-A^+A)y,A^+b\rangle
&=\langle (A^+)^T(I-A^+A)y,b\rangle.
=\langle US^+V^T(I-VS^+U^TUSV)y,b\rangle
\end{align}
The point is that
\begin{align}
(A^+)^T(I-A^+A)&=US^+V^T(I-VS^+U^TUSV)\\ \ \\
&=US^+V^T-US^+V^TVS^+U^TUSV\\ \ \\
&=US^+V^T-US^+S^+SV\\ \ \\
&=US^+V^T-US^+V^T\\ \ \\
&=0.
\end{align}
So the inner product in $(1)$ is zero, and it follows that the two vectors $A^+b$ and $(I-A^*A)y$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Thank you! So in general for proving orthogonal, does the question really breaks down to prove their inner product equal to zero? Another thing is that why we do not need to care about y and b. Is it because that since the previous part is 0, then 0* y = 0, and  0 * b = 0?

Comment: "Inner product equal to zero" is precisely what "orthogonal" means. As for your other question, you need to read my answer more carefully; it doesn't show that each of the two vectors in the inner product is zero.